# Fabricating a Strong Hub Shell for a Bicycle

Tags: machining, strength, cnc, bicycles, metalwork

I'd asked [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/91758/cncing-strong-hub-shell-kindernay-swap-cage/91770#91770) over at SE Bicycles but they think this is more an engineering question.

The flange on my hub broke and I'm having to get one fabricated. The part is actually a cage that houses an internal gear hub. It will go from looking something like this:

[image: Kindernay Swap]

to something like this:

[image: Pipe]

Where I'm at, 5-axis machines are hard to find, and the process will likely involve lathes and drill presses. One engineer even offered to laser cut the flanges and weld them to a tube.

In trying to meet the essentials (number of holes, inner diameter, hub width, cflange width) what are some consierations for keeping this simple yet strong? Do the geometric cut-outs in the center seem to serve a structural purpose such as to allow this cage to expand when tightened [as this user suggested](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/91770/61407)
? Or will simply drilling large holes serve as a suitable weight-saving measure? I noticed that the orginal flanges are titled inward ever so slightly and there are similar lip and notches here and there that will have to be plain old 90° angles on mine.

More pictures of the Kindernay Swap Cage [can be found here](https://m.pinkbike.com/buysell/3043803/). You'll notice it's bolted on one side and pressed up to a beveled edge on the other side (it will be hard to replicate the angle I'm told).

Comment: your question has somehow double posted ... please delete this one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fabricating a Strong Hub Shell for a Bicycle](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58411/fabricating-a-strong-hub-shell-for-a-bicycle)